# Pyenv не обрабатывает разные patch-версии python

Tags: python, pyenv

Я использую `pyenv 2.3.35` на `MacOS Sonoma 14.3` (чип M2), установленный через `brew`.

Я выполнил `pyenv install 3.8.18`, далее, находясь внутри папки `/Users/user/xxx/yyy/Projects` выполнил `pyenv local 3.8.18`. В результате в папке запускался `python 3.8.18`.

Через пару недель мне также понадобился `python 3.8.17`. Я выполнил `pyenv install 3.8.17`, далее, находясь внутри уже другой папки `/Users/user/zzz/Projects` выполнил `pyenv local 3.8.17`. Теперь когда я запускаю `pyenv versions`, то получаю 3 версии: `3.8.17, 3.8.18, system`. Указано, что выбрана версия `3.8.17`, однако когда я выполняю `python --version`, то получаю версию `3.8.18`.

Я выполнил `pyenv uninstall 3.8.18`. В результате у меня осталось 2 версии: `3.8.17, system`. Я снова запускаю `pyenv versions` внутри `/Users/user/zzz/Projects` и получаю, что выбрано `3.8.17`, однако, когда я выполняю `python --version`, то получаю ошибку:

```
Library not loaded: /Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.8.18/lib/libpython3.8.dylib
Referenced from: <120C8B80-012B-3016-9CC7-6717BDFDA264> /Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.8.17/bin/python3.8
Reason: tried: '/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.8.18/lib/libpython3.8.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.8.18/lib/libpython3.8.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.8.18/lib/libpython3.8.dylib' (no such file)
```

Я пытался сделать `pyenv rehash`, но это не решает проблему. Чтобы все заработало нужно удалить `3.8.17` и установить заново.
Но я не понимаю, почему 2 версии, которые отличаются только номером патча не работают вместе и удаление одной версии вызывает ошибку у другой.

Если я использую версии, различающиеся минорными номерами (например, `3.8.x` и `3.11.x`), то все работает корректно.

Я использую `zsh` и в файле `.zshrc` установил настройки согласно документации `pyenv`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выяснилось, что в `.zshrc` было:

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -L${HOME}/.pyenv/versions/3.8.18/lib"
```

Убрав `-L${HOME}/.pyenv/versions/3.8.18/lib`, все заработало корректно.